# Simplification of symbolic vector and matrices representation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, wolfram-cloud

I'm new to the Wolfram Language programming and I cannot manage to do the following.

I wish to use Wolfram Cloud to simpilfy a heavy vector and matrix expression using symbolic complex vectors (`a` and `da`) of arbitrary dimenssion `K` under several assumptions (`Conjugate[a].a = K`, `da^H*a = 0`, `Conjugate[da].da = K`. `S` is an Hermitian matrix of size `K`).

I've tried to use the following code, but it does not appeared to be correct.

```
$Assumptions=
{s >0,v >0,t \[Element]Reals,K \[Element] PositiveIntegers,
x \[Element] Vectors[K,Complexes],
S  \[Element] Matrices[{K,K},Complexes],
S  == ConjugateTranspose[S],
a  \[Element] Vectors[K,Complexes] ,
Conjugate[a].a == K,
da  \[Element] Vectors[K,Complexes] , 
Conjugate[da].da == K,
Conjugate[da].a ==0,
Conjugate[a].da ==0}
```

For example, the following code should return output zero yet it does not.

```
Conjugate[a].da
```

I would like the Wolfram Cloud to present and later simplify expressions such as:

**x**^H [**I**_K - c1 **a** **a**^H] **S** [**I**_N - c1 **a** **da**^H] **x**

where c1 and c2 are some scalars, using the following code

```
Conjugate[x].(IdentityMatrix[K] - c1 Outer[Times, {a}, {Conjugate[a]}]). S.(IdentityMatrix[K] - c2 Outer[Times, {a}, {Conjugate[da]}]).x
```

In case the arbitrariness of the dimension `K` is very problematic. It can be assumed to be explicitly fixed instead, e.g., `K = 6`.

Any help or corrections will be deeply appriciated.

Comment: I don't know what is expected, but I think you may need to use `$Assumptions={assum1,assum2,...}`.

Comment: \$Assumpyions does not accumulate expressions given in successive assignments. Each  successive assignment overrides the previous one. Read the documentation concerning \$Assumpyions carefully.

Comment: Thank you bcegkmqs23 and m_goldberg! I've editted it and combined all assumptions as you instructed.
Nevertheless, it does not solve the problem.